# Attribute-error in google translator function

Tags: python, function, translation

I am trying to create a translator function with a google translator. The code I have so far is very basic:

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()
result = translator.translate('Mitä sinä teet')
```

But everytime I get the same error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

How do I solve this: thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with the package you are using.
You can use the package `translators` instead.

Here is an example on how to use it:

```
import translators as ts
result = ts.google('Mitä sinä teet', to_language='en')
print(result)
```

You can find a more detailed explanation in [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/language-translation-using-python-bd8020772ccc) or in the [official documentation](https://pypi.org/project/translators/).